# DC current through diodes in AB amplifier

Tags: amplifier, diodes

I can't figure out how the DC current through the diodes is calculated in eq. 8.22 on [this PDF](https://coefs.uncc.edu/dlsharer/files/2012/04/F4.pdf) from University of North Carolina.

$$
I_D = \frac{V_{CC}/2-V_{BE}}{R_f+R_2}
$$

\$I_D\$ should be equal to the current through the resistor \$R_2\$ minus the current going through the base of the transistor \$Q_1\$. I am able to obtain this equation only supposing \$I_B = 0\$, which is not true, specially because they are matching the diode to the transistor to avoid thermal problems.

[image]

Comment: *I am able to obtain this equation only supposing IB=0* So they're assuming that the transistors have a large \$\beta\$? That is quite common.

Comment: *which is not true, specially because they are matching the diode to the transistor to avoid thermal problems.* How does this prevent us from assuming that \$\beta\$ is high enough to assume that \$I_B\$ = 0. The diodes and transistors aren't matched but thermally coupled and that makes the DC biasing current through the transistors more constant over temperature. This works because the forward voltage of a diode and the \$V_{BE}\$ of a transistor have a similar temperature coefficient. This is about the **voltages**. How is the base current relevant to that?

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie The base current is relevant because it affects the voltage drop over \$R_2\$

Comment: @user253751 That is true **however** in practice in a **proper design** the base current is **highly unpredictable** this is because \$\beta\$ is also unpredictable. Look up the datasheet of any transistor and note how the range over which \$\beta\$ varies is quite large. Values like min/typ/max = 50/100/200 are not uncommon. So there can be a **factor 4** difference in base current. You don't want that to affect the behavior of your circuit. So that's why designers choose the current through R2 to be **much larger** than the larges base current (smallest \$\beta\$).

Comment: So yes you're right, the base current does affect the current through R2 but in a good (robust) design, that variation should be quite small. Also, how much influence does a current change have on the forward voltage of a diode? Realize that the relation \$V_{D,forward} => I_{Diode}\$ is exponential. In electronics many things influence each other, the question is, which relations are strong and which are less? Which ones do I have to account for and which ones can I safely ignore?

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie We can't selectively ignore numbers because they are unpredictable. "We can't predict who will get cancer, therefore we can ignore cancer for the purpose of mortality statistics"

Comment: @user253751 No, I think you are misunderstanding. Since the beta is known to vary significantly, the design can not depend on a specific value or beta or a specific value of base current. So, the normal design approach is to make the dc current through R2 much greater than the worst case base current...the base current becomes negligible so we neglect it in the calculations.

Comment: @user253751 You're missing the point. We don't "just ignore the number" because it is too unpredictable. We design things in such a way (make the current through R2 much larger than the largest expected base current) that the base current becomes less relevant. What you say: ignore because I do not know. What I say: work around what I do not know by making the unknown a non-problem. But feel free to do all your electronics design and taking everything into account. I will be finished sooner as I make choices (that I can explain) that make my design work easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that equation assumes Ib=0.  We all know that can't be true IRL, but if the transistors aren't in saturation, it's likely that Ib is far lower than the bias currents used in the resistor/diode network.  So the estimate isn't a perfect solution in the real world, but it's close enough...and engineering is never about perfection, it's all about being close enough.

Comment: Thank you. I agree with you, only I would have stated before in the document that \$\beta\$ was large. I did a simulation of the circuit with \$\beta = 40\$ and \$I_B\$ was 3 mA, while \$I_{R2}\$ was 16 mA. Also I would have used this symbol \$\approx\$ instead of equal.